# Frame Gesture Recognizer doesn't work in ios simulator Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to make clickable frame. Here is my code:

```
  var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
        {
           await FrameClicked(user, DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());   
        };

  currentseasonbutton.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

XAML:

```
        <Frame Grid.Column="0" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" HeightRequest="120" VerticalOptions="Start" x:Name="currentseasonbutton">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image Source="bookingicon.png" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                <StackLayout Spacing="7" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="Booking List" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label x:Name="currentSeason" TextColor="#7D7D7D" FontSize="11" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

It works in Android simulator, but not in IOS simulator. What may be the reason?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in iOS?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  Have you used the debugger to verify if the delegate is being called?  Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Delegate is not being called. Its like it doesn't recognize the tap. If i put button instead of frame, everything works.

Comment: Can you please share us the whole xaml you are using? I use your code and it works well on my side.

Comment: My full xaml: https://pastebin.com/cKHstwn5

Comment: @LukaŠtroliga Are you using iOS 13.4 simulators? If so, you may be experiencing this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10162

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

I have edited your question body and indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. 

Good luck!

Comment: I test it again and it did work. I test in iOS simulator with system 13.1 and Xamarin.forms 4.5.0.530.

Comment: I am using iOS 13.4 simulator. So its probably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Same here.

Seems with iOS 13.4 Simulator GestureRecognizers do not work at all.

But with old Simulator with iOS 12.1 GestureRecognizers only sometime work and not on all objects, but in REAL iOS all work.